# Error while inflating layout because of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-appcompat, android-textinputlayout

I am getting error like this while inflating layout:

```
Failed to inflate
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

in Activity file:

```
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.education_details);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_contact,null);
```

Some answers suggested that error is generated because of style. So here is my style.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and then in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

layout file(content_contact.xml):

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Dependencies in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

If I don't use TextInputLayout, then it works perfectly. 
I tried several answers but none of them worked for me. 
How to solve this error?

Comment: are you sure for add design support library in your project. and Where are you work eclipse or studio.

Comment: @vaibhavrockstar check now . i have edited question with dependencies.

Comment: @AksharPatel look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your this code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

and Add this code

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "AppTheme" is not set for the inflated view. You can fix this by initialising the LayoutInflater with a ContextThemeWrapper:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AppTheme));
```